# Anatomically Correct Scorpion Men

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, anatomy, insectoid, anatomically-correct

The scorpion men are unique beings. They are humanoid above the waist, but below they have a scorpion's trunk and tail. The trunk does not have the usual limbs, but instead has avian wings in place of claws, and a single pair of tetrapod legs replacing the scorpion legs

How could these creatures work on the inside? Specifically relating to the joints and muscles around the scorpion's prosoma

Comment: Brain sends funny minerals to the muscle, the proteins inside the muscles react by contracting and pulling one onto the other until the brain gives signal to stop.

Comment: I don't understand your description. Please include a picture. It sounds like he is a scorpion-centaur except the front two legs are wings? What does a "single pair of tetrapod legs". Surely you need four legs to be a tetrapod???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scorpion people will need an internal skeleton of some sort

The scorpion trunk could be supported by something like a ribcage, supplementing the exoskeleton, and the tail could simply contain a vertebrate's tail. The vertebrae would be extended to match with the scorpion segments

The legs can be regular tetrapod legs, with a lizardly shoulder attaching it to the ribcage

The human part would simply lack a pelvis, with the spine going straight into the scorpion spine, on the face

The wings would be like avian wings, but instead of attaching to a shoulder they would articulate with a second humerus, which would allow the wings to bend backwards. This humerus would attach with another pair of shoulders, this pair higher up